# Java swagger private and public documentation

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

Is there a way to make swagger private documentation? I have documentation that needs to be accessible and public and some "admin" methods just for my colleagues. Does the swagger have such functionality?

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**SpringFoxConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public Docket admin() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/admin/**"))
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("mypackage"))
            .build()
            .groupName("admin")
            .tags(new Tag(USER, "User controller"))
            .apiInfo(apiDetails())
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
}
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my package"))
            .build()
            .groupName("api")
            .tags(new Tag(USER, "User controller"))
            .apiInfo(apiDetails())
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
}
```

So I want my admin endpoints be accessible only for admins.

I do not use .yaml file for my docs, just annotating methods.

Comment: `Spring Security?`

Comment: @emotionlessbananas. I understand that I can make private access for ./swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=admin via Spring Security. But I want to do this via swagger.